# MacOS - Tmux cant resize pane vertically

Tags: tmux

I am on mac High Sierra. Somehow I cant resize the pane vertically. When I split it vertically, there is dotted line to define the split line. I can't resize using ctrl+b - alt + <- or alt + ->.

When I resize it horizontally (ctrl + b - "), There is no dotted line and I can resize it fine using ctrl+b - alt + up/down.

Can any one help?

*Update: Nevermind about the dotted line, it's my Monaco font that causing it.*

Comment: The resizing works fine for me on macOS Mojave on iTerm2 and Alacritty. Can you share your `tmux.conf` file?

Comment: Try changing the keys binded to resize to a different one and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because option + arrow key is used to jump words. Make sure you are using xterm key mappings.

I just ran into this issue with iterm2. If you have selected a natural key mapping profile or terminal compatible profile, you won't be able to resize tmux panes are option + <- and -> are used to jump words.

You can either jump words or resize panes, as both use the same hex code sequence internally, which is causing a conflict.